# How to search through a list of columns to find a specific regular expression pattern, and create a new column based on this value?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of columns in a set of CSV files I am searching for and assigning new column names based on.

I want to search through the list of columns to find the case where a date variable (YYYY-MM-DD) is contained in the name (I don't know what the date will be or if it will even exist). I do know that there will most likely be a variable `col_of_interest_variable` that I definitely want to exclude.

I then want to search through the list of date containing columns, and choose the latest one. I have part of the function but am not sure the best way to search through a list of columns and create a NEW list containing all columns matching this formula:

Oh also, the rub with this function is that I am reading in hundreds of CSV files all containing different #s of columns with different names. The one thing I do know is that the pattern below, containing the most recent date, is the column I want.

`col_of_interest_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_variable`

Here is what I currently have and it doesn't work the way I want it to:
The findall method doesn't seem like the best approach, and the list comprehension to get the date_cols doesn't get the most recent date.

```
    filtered_columns = [
        re.findall("col_of_interest_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_variable", column)
        for column in df.columns
    ]
    if len(filtered_columns) == 0:
        df["new_col_of_interest"] = np.nan

    if len(filtered_columns) == 1:
        df["new_col_of_interest"] = df[col_of_interest_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_variable]

    elif len(filtered_columns) > 1:
        date_cols = next(s for s in filtered_columns if s)

        application_dates = [
            pd.to_datetime(re.search("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", column).group())
            for column in date_cols
        ]
        last_application_date_index = np.argmax(application_dates)

        df["new_col_of_interest"] = df[
            filtered_columns[last_application_date_index]
        ]
```

[image]

My goal is to have this Dataframe output, with a new column `new_col_of_interest` containing the values (in this case) from the `new_col_of_interest_2020-08-28_variable` column.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the regex you've written only returns one match or no matches at all
and that at least one column name will have a date the way you want it then you could try the below.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    matches = re.findall('col_of_interest_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_variable', col)
    if matches:
        match = matches[0]
        date = match.split('_')[-2]
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%d-%m')
        if idx == 0 or date>latest_date:
            latest_date = date
            latest_match = match
df['new_col_of_interest'] = df[latest_match]
```

You could change the format of the date if you need to in `strptime()`.

Answer (score 0):

use a sample columns.

```
col_List = ['col-2021-01-02_end',
 'col-2021-01-04_end',
 'col-2021-01-05_end',
 'col-2021-01-07_end',
 'col-2021-01-06_end',
 'a',
 'c',
 'col-2021-01-03_end',
 'col-2021-01-10_end',
 'd',
 'b',
 'col-2021-01-01_end-2021-01-15',
 'col-2021-01-08_end',
 'col-2021-01-09_end']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_List)
```

```py
# use str.findall to find the date in cols, and zip with the real columnname
df_col = pd.DataFrame(zip(df.columns, df.columns.str.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')))

# use explode to Transform each element of a list-like to a row
# drop colname which does not contain date
df_col = df_col.explode(1).dropna()

# find the max date in the col, or can set other condition
# filter the target columns
cond = df_col[1] == df_col[1].max()
print(df_col[cond])

                                    0           1
    11  col-2021-01-01_end-2021-01-15  2021-01-15

print(df_col)

                                    0           1
    0              col-2021-01-02_end  2021-01-02
    1              col-2021-01-04_end  2021-01-04
    2              col-2021-01-05_end  2021-01-05
    3              col-2021-01-07_end  2021-01-07
    4              col-2021-01-06_end  2021-01-06
    7              col-2021-01-03_end  2021-01-03
    8              col-2021-01-10_end  2021-01-10
    11  col-2021-01-01_end-2021-01-15  2021-01-01
    11  col-2021-01-01_end-2021-01-15  2021-01-15
    12             col-2021-01-08_end  2021-01-08
    13             col-2021-01-09_end  2021-01-09
```